# Scope of dynamic (multidimm) array when initialized with pointer and new

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

I'm royally confused right now. I have seen similar questions asked, and my implementation seems to be along the lines of these solutions, but I just can't get it to work.

I need to have a `UtilClass` that can initialize and dump a multi-dimensional dynamic array. I just want to pass the pointer the the array in `BaseClass`  that I want initialized along with the dims. I chose to use the `new` keyword instead of `malloc()`, but I'm worried that the scope of the pointers is limited to the `init` function and not to the lifetime of the `BaseClass` (or the array pointer for that matter) and that's why the `dump` function produces a SEGFAULT.

Here is some code to explain:

```cpp
// BaseClass.h
#pragma once
include "UtilClass.h"

class BaseClass
{
public:
  UtilClass* util{nullptr};
  double** array{nullptr};
};


// BaseClass.cpp
#include "BaseClass.h"

BaseClass::BaseClass() {
  util = new UtilClass();
  util->init(array, 4, 6);
  util->dump(array, 4, 6);
}
```

```cpp
// UtilClass.h
#pragma once

class UtilClass {
  void init(double** array, int rows, int cols);
  void dump(double** array, int rows, int cols);
};

// UtilClass.cpp
#include "UtilClass.h"

void UtilClass::init(double **darray, int rows, int cols) {
  int i,j;
  array = new double*[rows];
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      array[i] = new double[cols];

  for (i = 0; s < rows; i++)
      for (j = 0; a < cols; j++) {
          data[i][j] = 1;
          std::cout << "Data in array " << data[i][j] << std::endl; // This obviously works
      }
}

void dump(double** array, int rows, int cols) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
          std::cout << array[i][j] << " "; // But this produces a SEGFAULT
      std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start off with a piece of advice: it's best to reuse existing tools. Consider using `std::vector` for dynamically-allocated array. This is well tested, optimized and easy to use. Otherwise, you'll need to deal with conundrums of memory management (e.g. deallocate the allocated chunks of memory in the dtor of `BaseClass`).

Regarding your question: when you call `init`, you pass the pointer by value. This means that the `init` method allocates some memory and stores the pointer to it in its local copy of `darray`. At the end of `init` this local variable is gone (you lose access to it, leaking whole allocated memory). Change the method to:

```
  void UtilClass::init(double ***array, int rows, int cols) {
  int i,j;
  *array = new double*[rows];
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      (*array)[i] = new double[cols];

  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
          (*array)[i][j] = i*j;
          std::cout << "Data in array " << (*array)[i][j] << std::endl; // This obviously works
      }
  }
```

When calling dump, you need to pass 4 and 6 (and not 5 and 6).

Comment: Thank you so much. The proposed solution works and your explanation helped to wrap my head around it.

Regarding using std::vector - I would love to, but I'm working around existing structures so it would use more time than I have to change this now.